Remove Columns with all NULL values
In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I'm trying to remove the months that are completely NULL. I've looked through many post and haven't found any solutions or I didn't understand the solution do to lack of knowledge.
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 11 2024 17:25:03

I appreciate any help with this issue!
-- Step 1: Identify months with holiday sales
WITH SalesWithStoreType AS 
(
    SELECT 
        S.Store,
        ST.Type,
        S.Date,
        S.Weekly_Sales
    FROM
        [dbo].[store_dept_sales] AS S
    JOIN
        [dbo].[stores] AS ST ON S.Store = ST.Store
    WHERE
        S.IsHoliday = 1
),
MonthlySales AS 
(
    SELECT
        Type,
        MONTH(S.Date) AS month,
        SUM(S.Weekly_Sales) AS total_sales
    FROM
        SalesWithStoreType S
    GROUP BY
        Type, MONTH(S.Date)
),
-- Step 2: Generate pivoted results for only the months with holiday sales
PivotedSales AS 
(
    SELECT
        Type,
        January = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        February = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        March = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 3 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        April = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 4 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        May = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 5 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        June = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 6 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        July = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 7 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        August = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 8 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        September = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 9 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        October = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 10 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        November = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 11 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C'),
        December = FORMAT(MAX(CASE WHEN month = 12 THEN total_sales ELSE NULL END), 'C')
    FROM 
        MonthlySales
    GROUP BY 
        Type
)
SELECT
    Type,
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
FROM 
    PivotedSales
WHERE
    January IS NOT NULL
    OR February IS NOT NULL
    OR March IS NOT NULL
    OR April IS NOT NULL
    OR May IS NOT NULL
    OR June IS NOT NULL
    OR July IS NOT NULL
    OR August IS NOT NULL
    OR September IS NOT NULL
    OR October IS NOT NULL
    OR November IS NOT NULL
    OR December IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    type;


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

If you want dynamic columns you need dynamic SQL. T-SQL is a compiled language and you need to be specific on what columns you want. You can't not return a column because every row in that column has the value NULL.

Also, telling us what version of SSMS you are using isn't helpful; what would be is the version of SQL Server.

Haha, how funny, most people want to add the missing months, not remove the null ones haha

My recommendation is that you (1) Insert the results of your MonthlySales CTE into a temporary table or table variable. (2) select the distinct months from that table where total sales is not null, and use those results to generate the desired PivotedSales dynamic SQL, (3) Execute that dynamic SQL. Look at other [sql-server] dynamic pivot questions for examples.

While I commend you on trying to give us all the needed version information, the one we really need is missing. Run the command select @@version to get the version of the actual SQL Server that you are connected to.

A where clause works on rows not columns. i.e. you cannot suppress the output of columns through a where clause.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use this code to find null columns and drop them:
DECLARE @FullTableName nvarchar(255) = 'dbo.CitySLA'
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @DropColumnSQL_ORIG NVARHCAR(500) = concat('ALTER TABLE ',@FullTableName,' DROP COLUMN ')
DECLARE @DropColumnSQL_CURRENT NVARHCAR(500)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CurrTable 
SELECT
    s.name as ColumnName
    ,concat('select @CountOUT = count(*) from ' , @FullTableName , ' where ' ,  s.name ,  ' IS NOT NULL') as CheckNotNullQuery
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.name) as RwnM
    INTO #CurrTable
    FROM sys.columns                           s
        INNER JOIN sys.objects                 o ON s.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas                sh on o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
        where type='U'
        and concat(sh.name,'.',o.name) =@FullTableName
DECLARE @TotalColumns int = (select count(*) from #CurrTable),@CurrRow int = 1 , @PastRow int = 1,   @SqlQuery nvarchar(1000),
@CountOUT int,@CountIN int, @ColumnName nvarchar(255)
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@CountOUT int OUTPUT';
WHILE @CurrRow<=@TotalColumns
    BEGIN
    SET @SqlQuery = (select CheckNotNullQuery from #CurrTable where RwnM = @CurrRow)
    SET @ColumnName = (select ColumnName from #CurrTable where RwnM = @CurrRow)
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlQuery,@ParmDefinition,@CountOUT=@CountIN OUTPUT;
    IF @CountIN = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Column Name = ' + @ColumnName + ' has no values '
            SET @DropColumnSQL_CURRENT = concat(@DropColumnSQL_ORIG ,@ColumnName)
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @DropColumnSQL_CURRENT
        END
    SET @PastRow =@CurrRow
    SET @CurrRow = @PastRow +1
END


This will drop the column from the table which i don't think is what the question is about, he just wants to remove them from resultset

I supposed that he want to drop columns, let's wait him to comment?

Sure, but perhaps you should add a warning, i don't want him running this and dropping his whole database :D

I appreciate all the help. I am not wanting to drop columns from the Table, I just need to exclude them from the results. So the results from the query would only return (Feb, Oct, Nov and Dec).

@siggemannen you are right :-)
